# Alias for a complete SQL statement? (in PostgreSQL psql)

Tags: postgresql, psql

In PostgreSQL 9.5 psql (for use within an interactive session), I wold like to create an alias to a complete SQL statement, analogous to a shell alias. The objective is to just get the output printed on the screen.

If I could enable formatted server output (in Oracle terms) from within a stored procedure, it would look like this:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION print_my_table()
RETURNS void
AS $$
    -- somehow enable output here
    SELECT * from my_table;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

This would be invoked as `print_my_table();` (as opposed to `SELECT x FROM ...`)

I know I can use 'RAISE NOTICE' to print from within a stored procedure, but to do that I would need to reimplement pretty-printing of a table.

Perhaps there is a completely different mechanism to do this?

(`my_table` stands for a complex SQL statement that collects server data accounting information, or a `my_table()` stored procedure returning a table)

**EDIT**

The solution provided by @Abelisto (using psql variables) enables the creation of aliases to arbitrary statements, beyond merely printing the result to the screen.

Comment: Maybe I am not fully understanding, but why not just make a view?

Comment: With a view I will still have to say `select * from <view>`; what I want is to just say `do_it()` and get the results printed.

Comment: This needs to be done _within_ psql or would it be acceptable to alias `psql -c "SELECT * FROM mytable;"` ?

Comment: Within an interactive psql session.

Comment: How are you planning on using this? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I want to be able to quickly check the status of the server (tablespace sizes, number of records in tables, etc.). Also some standard domain-specific queries for what I'm doing. In Unix shells I can create compact aliases; so I wondered whether I can do something similar within the "postgresql shell".

Comment: @Abelisto - this is cool (-v name='statement'). Operates how I'd like it to. But to have many of these I'd like to load them from a file (or from within the db). Is there such a thing as a 'stored variable'?

Comment: `\i do_it.sql` is feasible but messy (many files). This was my first thought, but I wanted to see if something more elegant is possible.

Comment: @Abelisto - this works and answers the question. I'll accept if you make an answer out of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is so called internal variables in the `psql` utility which will be replaced by its content (except inside the string constants):

```
postgres=# \set foo 'select 1;'
postgres=# :foo
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

It can be also set by the command line option `-v`:

```
psql -v foo='select 1;' -v bar='select 2;'
```

Create the text file like

```
\set foo 'select 1;'
\set bar 'select 2;'
\set stringinside 'select $$abc$$;'
```

and load it using `\i` command.

Finally you can create the file `~/.psqlrc` (its purpose is like `~/.bashrc` file) and its content will be automatically executed each time when `psql` starts.

Comment: Critical insight here is that an internal variable can contain a statement (which will be executed when the variable is invoked). The variables even get tab-expanded, like in (reasonably modern) Unix shells. So in this usage, they provide a close analog to shell aliases.

Comment: What if the command is longer than a few words such as `select 1;` ? Is there a way to store the command in a file and source it from the `set` ? Something like `\set foo source(path/to/command.sql)`